# Measuring vapour pressure in a closed system

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, pressure, vapor-pressure

My experiment requires the determination of vapour pressure from which I will calculate the number density (or number of moles of the molecule) later, for a closed system.

**Here's my setup :**

[image: Setup]

Liquid is placed in a steel container with the steel tube connecting it to a t-junction. One branch goes to the liq N2 immersed catch flask, followed by a pump. 
Other branch goes to a pressure transducer (Si sensor, which measures absolute pressure, linear from 0.2 atm to 4 atm).

**Procedure :** 
Liquid, in my case n-hexane, is frozen in the container using liq. N2. The gases in the container and the tubes are removed using pump. While the valves are closed, the liquid is brought to room temperature. The freeze-pump-thaw cycle is repeated twice again, to remove dissolved gases from the  liquid.

Later the liquid is brought to room temperature and the system is left for few hours for equilibrium while the container is immersed in a water bath.  Valve for pump is closed during this time, while the valve towards the pressure sensor is open. Temperature measurement of the water bath is done using thermocouple.

**Issues :** 
The pressure sensor reading is always more than the saturated vapour pressure of the liquid for a given temperature. This maybe due to a leak. From Raman measurements of gases in the tube it was found that some N2 is present in the system.

1. What would be a good way to determine the vapour pressure of the liquid in this closed system.
2. Would it be a good approximation to assume liquid-vapour equilibrium and use the tables of vapour pressure vs temperature to determine the corresponding value for my case.

Importantly, maximal error allowed in the determined vapour pressure value is up to 2%.

Thanks.

---

Updates :

Pressure reading while melting **n-hexane** at room temperature.

[image: n-hexane_melting]

Pump used is an oil pump.
[image: pump used]

Comment: What is the residual vacuum pressure, compared to vapour pressure ?

Comment: a) fix the leak, b) test with empty sample container, c) calibrate your thermocouple, d) how was your pressure sensor calibrated, e) why does it take a few hours to equillibrate?

Comment: Upon repeated freeze-pump-thaw the obtained pressure is below 0.0068 atm (~0.1psi or 0.68 kPa). Vapour pressure measurement for n-hexane gave ~5 psi (0.34 atm or 34.47 kPa). Temperature is  25.5 C / 296.6 K.

Thermocouple was calibrated by an standardization institute upto 1000K. Its error is below 0.2K from 285-1000K.

Pressure sensor is a NIST calibrated absolute sensor, calibrated between 0 to 3.4atm (https://sea.omega.com/tw/pptst/PX409-USBH.html)

Comment: What about dynamic measurement, watching how boiling point decreases with decreasing of pressure ?

Comment: *Seven millibars* residual pressure? Are you using a membrane pump?

Comment: @Poutnik I have not checked dynamic measurement against boiling point.

Comment: @Karl Probably,  a membrane pump. I will check and report here. Its a very common type found in organic chem labs.

Comment: @Karl Pressure sensor reading show, initially fast and then slow but gradual increase in the reading  when melting to the liquid I will add the relevant plot in the post.

Comment: Schlenck lines are run with oil pumps, which should go down to 0.01 mbar, 0.001 with fresh oil.

Comment: By "calibration", I mean "when did you last check the calibration?" If it was more than two days or two months ago (depending on who handled the instrument in the meantime), check it again. An OC lab full of solvent vapour is not a nice environment for delicate equipment.

Comment: @Karl Pressure calibration was not checked for ~6 months. Thanks for the advice. :-)   We work in  a clean room, fixed temperature and humidity. Pump is located in a different room and the tube runs through to my instrument. We are doing spectroscopy of the vapour and we need vap pressure for the analysis.

Comment: @ankit7540 I have not said you did. It was alternative arrangement suggestion, that could or could not be applied to your case.